# Why does nginx think my root directory is /usr/share/nginx and not /var/www/html as my configuration states?

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I am new to nginx and trying to get the hang of it. I've been reading the docs, and they say if use the directive `root` it should tell nginx where to find requests. For example, from my understanding, `root /var/www/html` should tell nginx to find requests in the directory `/var/www/html`, but my instance of nginx is not doing that. I am trying to load a file in that directory called `test.html`, but instead it is trying to look for the file in `/usr/share/nginx`. Note that this is a pretty fresh install of nginx and I have made few changes to the default config files. I also want to note the path prefix is set to `/usr/share/nginx`, but my understanding is using the `root` directive should override that. I am running Ubuntu 18.04 and installed nginx through apt. Let me know if you need any more information. Thanks!

nginx.conf - Please note this file has no uncommented root directives

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##


    gzip on;

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;

    map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
      default upgrade;
      ''      close;
    }

    server {
      listen 80;

      server_name kramericaindustries.hopto.org;
      rewrite ^/rstudio$ $scheme://$http_host/rstudio/ permanent;

      location /rstudio/ {
        rewrite ^/rstudio/(.*)$ /$1 break;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8787;
        proxy_redirect http://localhost:8787/ $scheme://$http_host/rstudio/;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
        proxy_read_timeout 20d;
      }

      location /heatmap/ {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8050;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      }

      }

      # location /test/ {
      #   root /home/grant/test;
      #   index index.html;
      # }
    }

    # server {
    #   listen 8050;

    #   server_name kramericaindustries.hopto.org;

    #   location /heatmap/ {
    #     proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8050;
    #     proxy_set_header Host $host;
    #     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    #   }
    #   location /test/ {
    #   }
    # }

    # server {
    #   location /test {
    #     root /home/grant/www;
    #   }
    # }
}

#mail {
#   # See sample authentication script at:
#   # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
#
#   # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#   # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#   # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
#
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:110;
#       protocol   pop3;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
#
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:143;
#       protocol   imap;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
#}
```

/etc/nginx/sites-available/default - Please note this file has been unchanged since I installed it and is where the `root` directive I'm referring to is.

```
##
# You should look at the following URL's in order to grasp a solid understanding
# of Nginx configuration files in order to fully unleash the power of Nginx.
# https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/
# https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/
# https://wiki.debian.org/Nginx/DirectoryStructure
#
# In most cases, administrators will remove this file from sites-enabled/ and
# leave it as reference inside of sites-available where it will continue to be
# updated by the nginx packaging team.
#
# This file will automatically load configuration files provided by other
# applications, such as Drupal or Wordpress. These applications will be made
# available underneath a path with that package name, such as /drupal8.
#
# Please see /usr/share/doc/nginx-doc/examples/ for more detailed examples.
##

# Default server configuration
#
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    # SSL configuration
    #
    # listen 443 ssl default_server;
    # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    #
    # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
    #
    # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
    #
    # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
    # Don't use them in a production server!
    #
    # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

    root /var/www/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name _;


    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #   include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    #
    #   # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
    #   fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    #   # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
    #   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    #}

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #   deny all;
    #}
}


# Virtual Host configuration for example.com
#
# You can move that to a different file under sites-available/ and symlink that
# to sites-enabled/ to enable it.
#
#server {
#   listen 80;
#   listen [::]:80;
#
#   server_name example.com;
#
#   root /var/www/example.com;
#   index index.html;
#
#   location / {
#       try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
#   }
#}
```

EDIT: There is a soft symlink in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default` which points to `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`.

Comment: As far as i remember it keeps error pages there, that is it'll show you a file from `/usr/share/nginx` if you hit 404, 500. The config seems fine and I think that the `test.html` should be available at `<server>:80/test.html`.

Comment: Unfortunately, the error pages are not located at `/usr/share/nginx` and trying `<server>:80/test/html` also did not work.

Comment: Not `test/html` - `test.html`. Root defines where to _start_ looking for files. Given the example with `/var/www/html` for `/test.html` it shall return `/var/www/html/test.html`. But if you access `/test/html` it will look for index files in `/var/www/html/test/html`. Index files are those defined with `index` directive. Also the config `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` is not included in `nginx.conf`. You need to move it to `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled` for NGINX to load it (don't forget to reload NGINX after moving). Now it's some other vhost that's handling answers, not the one we discuss.

Comment: I'm sorry I made a type as I was trying `<server>:80/test.html`. I also edited the question to specify that there is a symlink to `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled`. I also was able to answer my own question though! Thanks for you help as I'm just leaning nginx.

Comment: You're welcome. Here's a link for you to learn about server names https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK I've solved the issue by learning something new about nginx. The problem is the server block for port 80 in `nginx.conf` and `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default` were in conflict which I was unaware of. Though `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default` is listed as the default server (`listen 80 default_server`), nginx was using the server block in `nginx.conf` because this server block has the server name directive (`server_name kramericaindustries.hopto.org;`) which took precedence over the default_server. (Yes, I was using this domain name for testing.) nginx only uses one server block to fulfill the request.

Because the server block in `nginx.conf` did not specify a root, it used the nginx path prefix by default which is `/usr/share/nginx` which does not contain `test.html`. Therefore, the request failed. I added `root /var/www/html;` to `nginx.conf` and everything is now working as expected.